# ORDER BY items must appear in the select list

Tags: sql, sql-server

My query got an error, cannot union with other query. When I excute the query it come out this error message

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.

```
SELECT b.strDesc as Product,(SELECT COUNT(strProdType) FROM tblCurrTrx WHERE strMachid = a.strMachID  and 
    strProdType = b.strProdType  and strTransStatus='00' AND ysnCashJammed='0'  AND dtmCreated>='28/Jan/2020' AND 
    dtmCreated<'30/Jan/2020' AND strMachID = '01' and strPaymentMethod ='01') As Completed ,
    (SELECT COUNT (strProdType) FROM tblCurrTrx WHERE strMachid = a.strMachID and strProdType = b.strProdType and 
    strTransStatus IN ('01') AND ysnCashJammed='0'  AND dtmCreated>='28/Jan/2020' AND dtmCreated<'30/Jan/2020' AND strMachID = '01' and strPaymentMethod ='01') As Exception ,
    (SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT strTransStatus) FROM tblCurrTrx WHERE strMachid = a.strMachID and strProdType = b.strProdType and 
    strTransStatus IN ('00','01') AND ysnCashJammed='0'  AND dtmCreated>='28/Jan/2020' AND dtmCreated<'30/Jan/2020' AND strMachID = '01' and strPaymentMethod ='01') As ProdCnt ,
    (SUM(dblPaidAmt) )- SUM(((((a.intRM1Dispense * 1 + a.intRM5Dispense * 5) + a.intRM10Dispense * 10) + a.int10CentDispense * 0.1) +
    a.int20CentDispense * 0.2) + a.int50CentDispense * 0.5) as TotValue FROM tblCurrTrx a, tblProductType b WHERE(b.strProdType = a.strProdType) AND 
    strMachID = '01' AND ysnCashJammed='0' AND strTransStatus IN ('00','01')  AND a.dtmCreated>='28/Jan/2020' AND a.dtmCreated<'30/Jan/2020' AND 
    strMachID = '01'and strPaymentMethod ='01' GROUP BY a.strMachID, a.strProdType,b.strDesc, b.strProdType 

    UNION SELECT  b.strDesc as Product,(SELECT COUNT(strProdType) FROM tblCurrTrx WHERE strMachid = a.strMachID  and 
    strProdType = b.strProdType  and strTransStatus='00' AND ysnCashJammed='0'  AND dtmCreated>='28/Jan/2020' AND 
    dtmCreated<'30/Jan/2020' AND strMachID = '01' and strPaymentMethod ='02') As Completed ,
    (SELECT COUNT (strProdType) FROM tblCurrTrx WHERE strMachid = a.strMachID and strProdType = b.strProdType and 
    strTransStatus IN ('01') AND ysnCashJammed='0'  AND dtmCreated>='28/Jan/2020' AND dtmCreated<'30/Jan/2020' AND strMachID = '01' and strPaymentMethod ='02') As Exception ,
    (SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT strTransStatus) FROM tblCurrTrx WHERE strMachid = a.strMachID and strProdType = b.strProdType and 
    strTransStatus IN ('00','01') AND ysnCashJammed='0'  AND dtmCreated>='28/Jan/2020' AND dtmCreated<'30/Jan/2020' AND strMachID = '01' and strPaymentMethod ='02') As ProdCnt ,
    (SUM(dblPaidAmt) )- SUM(((((a.intRM1Dispense * 1 + a.intRM5Dispense * 5) + a.intRM10Dispense * 10) + a.int10CentDispense * 0.1) +
    a.int20CentDispense * 0.2) + a.int50CentDispense * 0.5) as TotValue FROM tblCurrTrx a, tblProductType b WHERE(b.strProdType = a.strProdType) AND 
    strMachID = '01' AND ysnCashJammed='0' AND strTransStatus IN ('00','01')  AND a.dtmCreated>='28/Jan/2020' AND a.dtmCreated<'30/Jan/2020' AND 
    strMachID = '01'and strPaymentMethod ='02'

    GROUP BY a.strMachID, a.strProdType,b.strDesc, b.strProdType  ORDER BY a.strMachID, a.strProdType
```

Comment: So what is your question? The error message is self explanatory.

Comment: Seems you have 2 accounts? https://stackoverflow.com/users/8191957/kumaresan-murugan

Comment: I try to combine to query into one using UNION.

Comment: The error message tells you what is wrong?

Comment: Without having table schema and sample data how someone can execute this long query. If you want to get it solved from us you should give the table schema and sample data in executable SQL Server statement by editing the question.

Comment: Did you try to add order by in your query?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is huge. easiest way t fix, addthe oder by elements to the select:

```
    SELECT a.strMachID, a.strProdType, b.strDesc as Product,(SELECT COUNT(strProdType) FROM tblCurrTrx WHERE strMachid = a.strMachID  and 
        strProdType = b.strProdType  and strTransStatus='00' AND ysnCashJammed='0'  AND dtmCreated>='28/Jan/2020' AND 
        dtmCreated<'30/Jan/2020' AND strMachID = '01' and strPaymentMethod ='01') As Completed ,
        (SELECT COUNT (strProdType) FROM tblCurrTrx WHERE strMachid = a.strMachID and strProdType = b.strProdType and 
        strTransStatus IN ('01') AND ysnCashJammed='0'  AND dtmCreated>='28/Jan/2020' AND dtmCreated<'30/Jan/2020' AND strMachID = '01' and strPaymentMethod ='01') As Exception ,
        (SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT strTransStatus) FROM tblCurrTrx WHERE strMachid = a.strMachID and strProdType = b.strProdType and 
        strTransStatus IN ('00','01') AND ysnCashJammed='0'  AND dtmCreated>='28/Jan/2020' AND dtmCreated<'30/Jan/2020' AND strMachID = '01' and strPaymentMethod ='01') As ProdCnt ,
        (SUM(dblPaidAmt) )- SUM(((((a.intRM1Dispense * 1 + a.intRM5Dispense * 5) + a.intRM10Dispense * 10) + a.int10CentDispense * 0.1) +
        a.int20CentDispense * 0.2) + a.int50CentDispense * 0.5) as TotValue FROM tblCurrTrx a, tblProductType b WHERE(b.strProdType = a.strProdType) AND 
        strMachID = '01' AND ysnCashJammed='0' AND strTransStatus IN ('00','01')  AND a.dtmCreated>='28/Jan/2020' AND a.dtmCreated<'30/Jan/2020' AND 
        strMachID = '01'and strPaymentMethod ='01' GROUP BY a.strMachID, a.strProdType,b.strDesc, b.strProdType 

        UNION 

SELECT a.strMachID, a.strProdType,  b.strDesc as Product,(SELECT COUNT(strProdType) FROM tblCurrTrx WHERE strMachid = a.strMachID  and 
        strProdType = b.strProdType  and strTransStatus='00' AND ysnCashJammed='0'  AND dtmCreated>='28/Jan/2020' AND 
        dtmCreated<'30/Jan/2020' AND strMachID = '01' and strPaymentMethod ='02') As Completed ,
        (SELECT COUNT (strProdType) FROM tblCurrTrx WHERE strMachid = a.strMachID and strProdType = b.strProdType and 
        strTransStatus IN ('01') AND ysnCashJammed='0'  AND dtmCreated>='28/Jan/2020' AND dtmCreated<'30/Jan/2020' AND strMachID = '01' and strPaymentMethod ='02') As Exception ,
        (SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT strTransStatus) FROM tblCurrTrx WHERE strMachid = a.strMachID and strProdType = b.strProdType and 
        strTransStatus IN ('00','01') AND ysnCashJammed='0'  AND dtmCreated>='28/Jan/2020' AND dtmCreated<'30/Jan/2020' AND strMachID = '01' and strPaymentMethod ='02') As ProdCnt ,
        (SUM(dblPaidAmt) )- SUM(((((a.intRM1Dispense * 1 + a.intRM5Dispense * 5) + a.intRM10Dispense * 10) + a.int10CentDispense * 0.1) +
        a.int20CentDispense * 0.2) + a.int50CentDispense * 0.5) as TotValue FROM tblCurrTrx a, tblProductType b WHERE(b.strProdType = a.strProdType) AND 
        strMachID = '01' AND ysnCashJammed='0' AND strTransStatus IN ('00','01')  AND a.dtmCreated>='28/Jan/2020' AND a.dtmCreated<'30/Jan/2020' AND 
        strMachID = '01'and strPaymentMethod ='02'

        GROUP BY a.strMachID, a.strProdType,b.strDesc, b.strProdType  ORDER BY a.strMachID, a.strProdType
```